# Using css to draw a line on the left and right(center) of a logo image

Tags: css

I would like to know how i could use css to have a line go through the center of a logo image. See link below:

[Example](http://www.practiceenglish.ca/img/example.png)

Thanks
Julian

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried modifying a header text solution but failed to get the line centered.

Comment: upvote coz someone forget where he is

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach using absolute positioning

```
<div>
    <div style="height:75px;border-bottom:1px solid black;width:30px;display:inline-block;position:absolute;top:0"></div>
    <img style="position:absolute;top:0;left: 45px" src="http://placehold.it/100x150" />
    <div style="height:75px;border-bottom:1px solid black;width:30px;display:inline-block;position:absolute;top:0;left:160px"></div>
</div>
```

<kbd>[example](http://jsfiddle.net/vmVUh/)</kbd>

Comment: Is there any way to do this without fixing the width of the strikethrough line ? So the line expands/shrinks as the browser changes width. Also I would like the logo with the lines to be centered on my page.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach, it uses an absolutely positioned span as the strike through, and a div with the span and image in it to position the strike through, here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/AFBCC/2/)

and here's the code.

```
<div class="logo-container">
    <span class="logo-line"></span>
    <img class="logo" src="http://api.ning.com/files/Fd0Hyt-VB-mLJyE6xLYZ**QLu2VVQfvnaIEzyxSO11rwdkqRti2q4ra1ES1p8jr1BpSEJSaRTmqdCOv-6CXzMGxmhyl-gUex/applelogo.gif" alt="apple logo"></img>
    <span class="logo-line"></span>
</div>
```

css:

```
.logo-container {
    position: relative;
    height: 87px;
    width: 35%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-width: 144px;
}

.logo {
    position: relative;
    width: 72px;
    height: 87px;
    z-index: 2;
}

.logo-line {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    top: -50%;
    width: 20%;
    height: 2px;
    background: #333;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, however i need a solution where the line expands and shrinks as the browser size changes. Similar to the header text with a line on each side.

Comment: Ok, I updated the code, is that more of what you were wanting? The lines grow/shrink when the browser is resized, and there are two line's on either side now.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
<span style="width:60px;"><div style="min-width:60px; max-width:60px; max-height:3px; min-height:3px; background-color:black; display: inline-block; position:relative; top:-20px;"></div></span>
<img src="http://api.ning.com/files/Fd0Hyt-VB-mLJyE6xLYZ**QLu2VVQfvnaIEzyxSO11rwdkqRti2q4ra1ES1p8jr1BpSEJSaRTmqdCOv-6CXzMGxmhyl-gUex/applelogo.gif" width="40px" height="47px"></img>
<span style="width:60px;"><div style="min-width:60px; max-width:60px; max-height:3px; min-height:3px; background-color:black; display: inline-block; position:relative; top:-20px;"></div></span>
```

I set the relative position of each div to -20px because 20 is half of the height of the logo image. So if your logo image SRC is 80 pixels tall than set both divs to `top:-40px;`

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Edd6j/2/